Excel Add in How to connect server on successfully submit open the URL page and how to navigate to current url using routing react
please help me on this
import * as React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Navigate, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const URL = 'http:///auth/login/page';


const ServerConnect: React.FC = () => { 
    const [serverLink, setServerLink] = useState('http:///auth/login/page');
    const navigate = useNavigate()


    const handleSubmit = async(event: React.FormEvent) => {
       event.preventDefault();
       console.log('hiiii') 
       navigate(url)
    }

    return(
        <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form_submit">
                <div>
                <input 
                    type="text"
                    value={serverLink}
                    readOnly disabled
                />
                </div>

                <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
                
               
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}





export default ServerConnect





<Router>
      <Routes>
        
        <Route path="/" element= {<ServerConnect />} />
     
/* here how to add routing to that "URL path" */
        <Route path="*" element= {<Navigate to="/" />} />

      </Routes>

    </Router>

I am giving navigate () for routing to next page i.e.(http:///auth/login/page) but it is not going to another page for (e.g. about), please suggest me how to do in excel add in.
your text
reference image [enter image description here] (https://i.sstatic.net/A2O5jgD8.png)
I am expecting the way how to render the URL to next path `
